# obtain signal strength from packets on Mac OSX with Scapy

Tags: macos, wifi, scapy, rssi

## Background

I'm trying to acquire RSSI from received packets. I know they are available in Radiotap headers, but unfortunately I wasn't able to sniff any packet containing Radiotap headers in it.

I did find [parsePacket](https://github.com/azz2k/scapy-rssi/blob/master/scapy-rssi.py#L52-L73) method from [scapy-rssi](https://github.com/azz2k/scapy-rssi), which seems to only filter out packets containing Radiotap headers with RSSI (If I'm not mistaken).

I've utilized that method in the following code:

```
def parsePacket(pkt):
  if pkt.haslayer(scapy.all.Dot11):
    if pkt.addr2 is not None:
      # check available Radiotap fields
      field, val = pkt.getfield_and_val("present")
      names = [field.names[i][0] for i in range(len(field.names)) if (1 << i) & val != 0]
      # check if we measured signal strength
      if "dBm_AntSignal" in names:
        # decode radiotap header
        fmt = "<"
        rssipos = 0
        for name in names:
          # some fields consist of more than one value
          if name == "dBm_AntSignal":
            # correct for little endian format sign
            rssipos = len(fmt)-1
          fmt = fmt + self.radiotap_formats[name]
        # unfortunately not all platforms work equally well and on my arm
        # platform notdecoded was padded with a ton of zeros without
        # indicating more fields in pkt.len and/or padding in pkt.pad
        decoded = struct.unpack(fmt, pkt.notdecoded[:struct.calcsize(fmt)])
        return pkt.addr2, decoded[rssipos]

def packetCallback(pkt):
  parsed = parsePacket(pkt)
  if parsed:
    print(parsed)

sniff("en1", prn=packetCallback)  #en1 is a wlan interface on my OSX
```

Unfortunately function was not outputting anything - therefore no packets contained Radiotap headers. I tried activating an monitor mode with `sniff("en1mon", prn=packetCallback)`, but there was no progress.

---

## Main Problem:

I also found, somewhere that en1 interface of Mac OSX does not have access to Dot11 headers, is that true? If that's the case, then how can I get RSSI value from packets on OSX?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

- don’t use scapy-rssi, it is mostly not needed nowadays
- use the latest dev version of scapy: https://github.com/secdev/scapy/archive/master.zip  (which has improved support for RSSI, not released yet)

You may then want to use `packet[Radiotap].dBm_AntSignal` directly, which will be a negative value when not None, instead of the whole parsePacket thing.

Lastly, on OSX you might need to use `sniff([...], monitor=True)` to be sure to properly receive the raw packets

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect it to work since from what I know en1 interface does not read Radiotap headers. But now it worked perfectly! Was it due to Scapy enabling support for en1 interface? Thank you!